# Redirect application logs to docker logs

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My Docker container produces multiple application logs.

`docker logs` command only shows the app startup logs. Is there a way to redirect the other log files so they are shown by the `docker logs` command?

EDIT:

I'm using the [WebSphere](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/websphere-traditional/) traditional docker image. Docker logs only shows the startServer.log but there are other logs like SystemOut.log ....

Comment: This depends on your application right? Docker logs is only showing the aggregation of stdout and stderr from the process running in the container.

Comment: This could be a hacking operation I think. Not for such a case with docker design. Like @johnharris85 said, only STDOUT and STDERR could be shown by `docker logs`. All u wanna achieve, that maybe could be done with several `tail -f` in your Dockerfile, but it's really not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information, like which application, your Dockerfile, etc.

As a general answer you must have an entry point script which will send your application log to stdout:

```
runapp &
tail -f logfile
```

Something like that.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`docker logs` will display all the stdout and stderr from the application running in the container. Configure the application to log to stderr instead of a log file and the logs will be visible from `docker logs`.