# How can I take logs of a running docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I need to run the docker container with logs redirected to a file in a shared location. I searched a lot for but didn't a solution for this.
what I tried is:
Run the docker container first
docker run --name sample -d -p 8083:8080 xxxxx.yyyy.zzz/test/test-application:latest

then I ran 
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/logs:/opt/logs sample
but when i check /home/ubuntu/logs folder, nothing is there.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount your external directory where you want logs to be stored when running the container.

```
docker run --name sample -d -p 8083:8080 -v /home/ubuntu/logs:/opt/logs xxxxx.yyyy.zzz/test/test-application:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

you redirect it with a command such as

`docker logs sample > /home/ubuntu/logs`

see also

[Redirect application logs to docker logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431031/redirect-application-logs-to-docker-logs)

and

[how to redirect docker logs to a single file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144589/how-to-redirect-docker-logs-to-a-single-file)